# Polynomial Kernel

Tags: svm

Consider the polynomial kernel: $$K(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{x}') = (\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{x}'+c)^{d}$$

What exactly is the role of $c$? If $c$ is large, does this indicate that lower order terms play an important role in determining the similarity of $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}'$?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my thought. By [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),

$(\boldsymbol{x}^\top \boldsymbol{x}'+c)^d = \sum_{i=0}^d \binom{d}{i} (\boldsymbol{x}^\top \boldsymbol{x}')^{d-i} c^i. $

Assume $c\geq 0$. It can be seen that the term containing $(\boldsymbol{x}^\top \boldsymbol{x}')$ with lower degree will have higher multiplicative factor from $c^i$. So what you said is sensible.

Comment: If the kernel corresponds to a mapping $\phi(\boldsymbol{x})$, then the hyperplane is $\mathbf{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x} + b$. Lets say that the $j$-th component of $\mathbf{w}$, say $w_j$ corresponds to a lower degree component of $\phi(\boldsymbol{x})$, say $\sqrt{2\cdot c_j} x_j$. Now multiply the former by $\sqrt{c_j}$ and divide the latter by $\sqrt{c_j}$. Shouldn't we take the same hyperplane in both cases? I mean the only sensible values for $c$ looks like that are $0$ and $1$.